# How do I add an event to a specific public calendar using a flow and "New Event" action?

Tags: visual-workflow, calendar, recordtriggeredflow, public-calendar

First let me say that I'm new to salesforce so forgive me if I should be doing this another way.

I have a record-triggered flow with the goal to add a sales appointment to a public calendar named "Sales". This is triggered whenever the appointment start date and end date field are changed.

I added a new action called "New Event". I input the start date/time and end date/time with a subject.

I dont see any ways to add this event to a specific calendar. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the Public Calendar record ID using the 'Get Record' element before creating an event. Assign the Public Calendar record ID to the 'OwnerId' (Assigned to ID) field on the event. This should accomplish the task. Let us know if you face any issue. If Assigned to Id field is not available for your action then create Create Record to generate event.

[image]

Comment: What should I enter down below? Your image is cut off. Here's what I got so far. https://imgur.com/a/6D4H5PL

Comment: Automatically store all fields. You don't need to specific list of fields to be retrieved.

Comment: Am I doing the create record part correctly? https://imgur.com/a/JDzMAkM

Comment: I get this error when I run the flow using the values in my previous comment. https://imgur.com/a/xCbqIjL

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for leading me down the path!